# Qt - Is there any tool for generating code for consuming a SOAP web service?

Tags: qt, web-services, wsdl

I'm looking for a tool that can generate Qt code for classes and methods of a web service based on it's WSDL. Is there any tool like this for Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html). It's the most popular SOAP client library for C++, and has code generation.

Comment: [How to use gSOAP with Qt for Web Service Client?](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_gSOAP_with_Qt_for_Web_Service_Client)

Answer (score 5):

There is [KD SOAP](http://www.kdab.com/products/kd-soap) library , download the `LGPL` (was `GPL` earlier) version [here](https://github.com/KDAB/KDSoap) , you can also license it for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The [WSDL2Ws tool](http://axis.apache.org/axis/cpp/arch/WSDL2Ws.html) that comes with [Axis C++](http://axis.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html) can be used to generate different types of wrapper classes / skeletons for the server side and wrapper classes / stubs for the client side for a given WSDL file. WSDL2Ws tool is written in Java and is based on the WSDL tools by Axis Java project.